# C++, Passing custom class object in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Can someone explain me how to pass a custom class object to another function in wxWidgets? I have a wxDialog class called AddUser which contains a void type OnButtonClick function that creates an object of a custom class "User". How can I pass that object to another OnButtonClick function that is located in Main class?

Comment: Why do you want to call directly to `OnButtonClick()`? Can't you just create a function in Main class that takes a `User*` as argument?

Comment: The OnButtonClick function in main serves displaying content of the object.

Comment: @Then just add a function that takes a `User*` and displays it. No need to call that other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important thing to know (in case you don't already) about `wxDialog` is that it is quite okay to create them on the stack (most wxWidgets windows should be created on the heap).

This means that your dialog instance remains available even after it has been closed by the user pressing "Ok". You can test for user responses by the following code:

```
... existing method ...

AddUser dialog (this);

if (dialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
{
    ... process new user ...
}
```

Because the dialog is still instantiated, you can include a method in your dialog code that returns the new user as follows:

```
User AddUser::GetUser ()
{
    return newUser;
}
```

However, you should of course be careful where the new user is actually created. For example, if the new user object is created locally in the dialog, then you will need to make a copy of it (as the above example will do). If it is created on the heap (which I wouldn't advise) then you can return a pointer. A third alternative would be to pass a reference to the `GetUser` method so the dialog method looks like this:

```
bool AddUser::GetUser (User& user)
{
    // Make sure that all fields are valid. Simple example given, but
    // should be more complete.
    if (TextName->GetValue() != "" && TextSurname->GetValue() != "")
    {
        user.setName(TextName->GetValue());
        user.setSurname(TextSurname->GetValue());

        return true;
    }
        return false;

    return newUser;
}
```

And the call looks like this:

```
void wxBiblioFrame::OnButAddUserClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    AddUser dialog(this);
    myUserDialog dialog (this);

    myUserClass newUser;

    if (dialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
    {
        if (dialog.GetUser (newUser))
        {
            ... process and store the new user ...
        }
        else
        {
            ... handle the error ...
        }
    }

    // NOTE: no need to Destroy() the dialog.
}
```

By the way, unless your user class is huge, I wouldn't be too concerned making copies of the object from an efficiency point of view. Creating and closing the dialog is likely to dwarf any time taken in making a copy.

Comment: I've changed few things and i don't know if what I'm trying to do is logical and possible the way I think. Here are the project files https://github.com/frezn08/wxBib. With AddUser i want to create an object and set up it's all variables and then pass it to the ShowList which would display it in the TextCtrl.

Comment: What you are trying to do is logical and possible, but I would suggest another way to do it. Take a look at `wxStdDialogButtonSizer` for the OK and Cancel buttons. Instead of having a `AddUser::OnButOKClick` the OK button will close it automatically. You can then populate your `User` object in a `GetUser` method (see my updated answer above). Other comments: 1) I wouldn't create a new user and new book in the same dialog. 2) For the ShowList, it would probably be better to have a wxListCtrl or wxDataViewListCtrl on the main frame.

Comment: Thank you very much for Your time and effort. I think im just too stupid for this.

Comment: I doubt that very much! I don't know how long you have been developing with wxWidgets, but it takes a little while to get used to. Afterwards, I think you will find it a very comprehensive and useful framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an OnClick event and pass something different than the parameters in the event signature. If you need somthing like tis then maybe you should consider reiterating your application's architecture.